# Angular services: is it bad practice to assign response to an object or should I only use resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have seen this code, which works for me but I wonder if it's bad practice to create an object inside the service- assign it to this and then to assign the response to the object in the success callback of the http get method.

```
.service("personDataService", function($http, $q) {

    var person = this;
    person.record = {};
    var endPoint = 'https://api.something.com';

    person.getInformation = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      $http.get(endPoint)
        .success(function(response) {
          /*
          here i'm assigning response to person.record and also using resolve. 
          but is this bad practice to assign response directly to person?
          */
          person.record = response;
          defer.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function(err, status) {
          defer.reject(err);
        })
      return defer.promise;
    }

return person;
}
```

Then in my controllers code I am calling the personDataService.record directly to check if it's empty.

i.e.

```
Object.keys(personDataService.record).length
```

Is this bad practice to be using personDataService.album directly?

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

Comment: but your example removes the $q promise library. I'd like to keep the current structure...

Comment: It is not bad practice to assign the response to an object. The `$resource` service does it. That said, there are bad ways to use a `$resource` object if you don't understand that it fills in the information after the XHR completes and handle it appropriately.  Checking for `Object.keys.length` looks like one of the bad ways. Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if instead of assigning a response to an object to use then method from inside your controller and have the response delivered there. Another thing that you shoud do is to remove the $http legacy promise methods success and error that have been deprecated and use the standard then method. This is an example of how to use then method.

```
angular.module('starter')
.factory('services', services);

function services($http) {
        var services = {
            someService: someService,
        };
        return services;

        //someService service
        function someService() {
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.something.com',
                headers: {
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'contentType': "application/json"
                }
            };
            return $http(req);
        };
    }
```

Then from your controller call the service like this:

```
services.someService().then(
      function(response) {
      //do whatever is needed with the response
        console.log(response);
      },

      function (error) {
        console.log(error); 
      }
    );
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question asked. It looks more like a commentary on OPs methods.

Comment: it is an example of how to use then() instead of success and error, just trying to help here by posting a working code example

Comment: I understand that, but it does not answer the question asked.